# Draw on canvas generated by html2canvas

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html2canvas

I need to use html2canvas' canvas as a normal canvas and draw a rectangle on it, but I can't seem to get it to work. Here's the code:

```js
html2canvas(document.getElementById('example-element'), {backgroundColor: null, scale: canvasScale,}).then(function(canvas) {       
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    });
```

I'm expecting a filled rectangle to appear, but nothing happens in the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably working but your drawings are offcanvas or begin clipped due to the modified masks/transforms set from html2canvas.

Resetting the transform for the context will probably fix it:

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById('example-element'), {backgroundColor: null, scale: canvasScale,}).then(function(canvas) {       
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.resetTransform(); // <---- this line is what you need
        ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    });
```